# Angular2 error in httpservice

Tags: angular, http, service

I learn Angular at 'https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6',but when compile ,it says 'not found angular-in-memory-web-api',so I add "angular-in-memory-web-api":"~0.3.0" in package.json.
but when it run ,it show nothing in hero-detail,and hero-search

all code are the same in https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6
can somebody help me

here is app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms'; // <-- NgModel lives here
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {DashBoardComponent} from './dashboard.component';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
import {HerosComponent} from './heros.component';
import {HeroService} from './hero.service';
import {HeroSearchComponent} from './hero-search.component';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';

//import for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import {InMemoryWebApiModule} from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import {InMemoryDataService} from './in-memory-data.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HerosComponent,
    DashBoardComponent,
    HeroSearchComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, // <-- import the FormsModule before binding with [(ngModel)]
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)
  ],
  providers: [HeroService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste your actual app.module.ts file into your question so we can see exactly what's happening?

Comment: import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms'; 
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {DashBoardComponent} from './dashboard.component';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
import {HerosComponent} from './heros.component';
import {HeroService} from './hero.service';
import {HeroSearchComponent} from './hero-search.component';

Comment: import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';

import {InMemoryWebApiModule} from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import {InMemoryDataService} from './in-memory-data.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HerosComponent,
    DashBoardComponent,
    HeroSearchComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, [(ngModel)]
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)
  ],
  providers: [HeroService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: Don't add code in comments, edit your question and add the code at the bottom. Make sure you format the code as code (highlight the code and click the { } icon in the editor toolbar, then confirm in the preview that it's formatted properly).

Comment: After you added "angular-in-memory-web-api":"~0.3.0" in package.json, did you run npm install in the terminal to update the dependencies and load the newly added package?

Comment: Yes ,I already do it